# psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "" WHERE toys.toy_id = ' '

Tags: python, flask, model

I am building a Flask app and I have two tables in my models.py. I am trying to connect them with a foreign key however I keep getting the following error message:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "" WHERE toys.toy_id = ' '
```

I thought I followed the documentation just fine but apparently not.

Here is my models.py:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, toys=''):
        self.toys = toys

class Toy(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'toys'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    toy_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self, toy_id=''):
        self.toy_id = toy_id
```

Here is my server.py file:

```
@app.route("/api/toy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def toy():
    incoming = request.get_json()
    toy = Toy.query.filter_by(toy_id=incoming["toy_id"]).first()
```

The last line is the line generating the error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think the problem in - request.get_json().

Comment: incoming["toy_id"] is empty. Just print **incoming** to see where you're wrong. If you need more help, please share us how you call the toy endpoint